# Can VS2015 running on hyper-v VM connect to VS Android Emulator on a different VM?

Tags: xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-2015, hyper-v

I'm developing Xamarin Android apps on Visual Studio 2015 (VS2015 Update 1) on Windows 10 Pro (latest build). **I've recently installed VS21015 on a hyper-v VM on my PC and want to connect it to the Visual Studio Android Emulator running on a different hyper-v VM on the same PC. Is this possible?**

I installed both VS Android Emulator and VS2015 using the standard installs and both work fine. However, I've not yet figured out a way to get VS2015 on VM#1 connected to the VS Android Emulator on VM#2.

Initially I tried installing the VS Android Emulator on the same VM as VS2015, however, nested VMs are not yet supported on hyper-v.

Thank You!

Comment: From VM#1, connect adb to VM#2's Andriod device (emulator or physically attached device), so from VM#1, in a shell cd to your Andriod SDK platform-tools are installed, and issue an `adb connect VM2IPAddress:PORT` and it will be available for deploy/debug in VS/Xamarin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the VS Emulator for Android is also a Hyper-V VM, you won't be able to run it in a Hyper-V VM. If you run Visual Studio in a Hyper-V VM and run the emulator on the host machine for that VM, you'll be able to manually connect to the emulator via adb connect

Comment: Looks like nested virtualization has arrived, I want to give this a try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/user_guide/nesting

Comment: Last I tried -- two days ago -- nested virtualization isn't working. I'm curious about the adb connect idea... can I attach to an emulator on a totally different machine, like my Mac which has Genymotion and numerous handset/API profiles on it?

Comment: Nested virtualization is now possible. See [this](http://www.appzinside.com/2016/01/28/developing-windows-phone-apps-in-a-hyper-v-environment-using-nested-virtualization/).